# The scope of `this` in ES6 classes

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am struggling to understand how `this` works within ES6 classes which makes it hard to build applications with any kind of consistency. Here is one example of my confusion within a React class:

```
class Class extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            timeout: 0
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {

        // Register with Flux store.
        // On change run this._storeUpdated()
    }

    _storeUpdated() {

        if (this.state.timeout < 3) {
            console.log(this.state.timeout); // 0
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    authorized: false,
                    timeout: this.state.timeout + 1 // undefined?
                });
                // Force Flux store to update - re-runs this method.
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this.state.timeout `undefined` within the call to `setState()`? However if I arrow function the method then it works:

```
_storeUpdated = () => {

    if (this.state.timeout < 3) {
        console.log(this.state.timeout); // 0
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                authorized: false,
                timeout: this.state.timeout + 1 // 1
            });
            // Force Flux store to update - re-runs this method.
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

What is actually going on here?

Comment: How exactly do you invoke it?

Comment: Within componentWillMount

Comment: (Using Flummox) `Flux.getStore('store').on('change', this._storeUpdated);`

Comment: `this._storeUpdated.bind(this)` or `() => this._storeUpdated()`. The problem has nothing to do with ES6: this behaviour was in ES forever.

Comment: That does not answer my question. That is just another fix.

Comment: It does - `this` is not defined there, because the context is lost when you pass just a reference to a function with `this._storeUpdated`

Comment: Then how is it that the console log still has access to this?

Comment: It's likely to collide with something else, not retrieved from the current instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82797/discussion-between-julien-vincent-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be confused because React does autobinding when using `React.createClass`, but it does not when inheriting from `React.Component` (i.e. the ES6 way). This change was explained in the [0.13 beta1 blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding).

In your specific case, and since you are using `Flux.getStore('store').on('change', this._storeUpdated);`, (which is a [method on EventEmitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3/blob/5562b8357c32e24f5788a0795bd347f4ded761d8/index.js#L125-L147), as [used by Flummox](https://github.com/acdlite/flummox/blob/804205a74facb0cee0024a1390c438955dc090d4/src/Flux.js#L15)) the context is set to the `EventEmitter` object, which has nothing to do with your component object and has no `state` attribute.

Note you can specify the value of `this` as the third argument when registering the event listener: `Flux.getStore('store').on('change', this._storeUpdated, <this-object>);`

For achieving autobind in ES6 classes, you should use any of the methods described in the React blog post. As a side note, and if you are into ES7, you can even use an [autobind decorator](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator).

Comment: `You might be confused because React does autobinding when using React.createClass` < that is exactly it. This answer reinforces what zerkms said in chat.